# What's the error that I can't add data to Jquery.datatables?

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#testTable4').dataTable({
                "bRetrieve": true,
                "bPaginate": true, //翻页功能
                "bLengthChange": true, //改变每页显示数据数量
                "bFilter": true, //过滤功能
                "bSort": true, //排序功能
                "bInfo": true,//页脚信息
                "bAutoWidth": true,//自动宽度

            "sScrollX":"80%",
            "sScrollY":"400px",
            "oLanguage": {
                "sProcessing": "正在加载中......",
                "sLengthMenu": "每页显示 _MENU_ 条记录",
                "sZeroRecords": "对不起，查询不到相关数据！",
                "sEmptyTable": "表中无数据存在！",
                "sInfo": "当前显示 _START_ 到 _END_ 条，共 _TOTAL_ 条记录",
                "sInfoFiltered": "数据表中共为 _MAX_ 条记录",
                "sSearch": "搜索",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sFirst": "首页",
                    "sPrevious": "上一页",
                    "sNext": "下一页",
                    "sLast": "末页"
                }
            },
            "aoColumns" : [
                { "mData" : "stuNumber"},
                { "mData" : "stuName"},
                {"mData" : "stuNamed"},
                {"mData" : "stuSex"},
                {"mData" : "stuNation"},
                {"mData" : "stuBirth"},
                {"mData" : "stuNative"},
                {"mData" : "stuRegious"},
                {"mData" : "stuPolitical"},
                {"mData" : "stuHealth"},
                {"mData" : "stuSpecial"},
                {"mData" : "stuResidence"},
                {"mData" : "stuSchoolRoll"},
                { "mData" : "regiousSeat"},
                { "mData" : "stuID"},
                {"mData" : "stuAddress"},
                {"mData" : "stuMobile"},
                {"mData" : "stuEmail"},
                { "mData" : "stuEntranceWay"},
                {"mData" : "stuAlone"},
                { "mData" : "stuMartyr"},
                { "mData" : "stuSingle"},
                {"mData" : "stuFarmer"},
                { "mData" : "stuEnteranceDate"},
                { "mData" : "stuClass"}
                ]
    });
    })
</script>`
```

First, I creat a datatable with dataTable().
Then I write a table use ID=testTable4.

```
<table id="testTable4" class=" display table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="80%" bgcolor="#2c5959">
    <caption>TEST TABLE</caption>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>学号</th>
        <th>姓名</th>
        <th>曾用名</th>
        <th>性别</th>
        <th>民族</th>
        <th>出生日期</th>
        <th>籍贯</th>
        <th>宗教信仰</th>
        <th>政治面貌</th>
        <th>健康状况</th>
        <th>特长</th>
        <th>户口性质</th>
        <th>学籍状态</th>
        <th>户口所在地</th>
        <th>身份证号</th>
        <th>居住地</th>
        <th>电话号码</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>入学方式</th>
        <th>是否留守儿童</th>
        <th>是否烈士子女</th>
        <th>是否独生子女</th>
        <th>是否进城务工子女</th>
        <th>入学年月</th>
        <th>班级</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>

</table>
```

Now I want Add some data to this table, so here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addData() {
        $.ajax({

            type:"POST", //请求方式
            url:"${pageContext.request.contextPath}../src/servlet.GetStuInfoServlet",//请求路径
            cache: false,
            data:"classNumber=1401",//传参
            dataType: 'Json',//返回值类型

            success:function(string){

                var stuStr = JSON.stringify(string)
                var stuObj = JSON.parse(stuStr);
                        $('#testTable4').dataTable().fnAddData(stuObj);

            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Here is the response data:

```
{"data":[{"stuSingle":"否","stuSex":"男","stuID":"1000383897","stuEntranceWay":"特效拍照","stuFarmer":"否","stuEnteranceDate"
:"2007","stuPolitical":"思密达","stuNative":"韩国","stuSpecial":"拍照","stuSchoolRoll":"正常","regiousSeat":"
无","stuMobile":"11000111010","stuAddress":"上海市奉贤村","stuRegious":"无","stuBirth":"1988","stuNumber":"12345678"
,"stuAlone":"否","stuClass":"1401","stuEmail":"pengpeng_yu@163.com","stuHealth":"健康","stuName":"权志龙","stuMartyr"
:"否","stuResidence":"城市","stuNamed":"权志龙","stuNation":"韩国"},{"stuSingle":"否","stuSex":"男","stuID":"1000383898"
,"stuEntranceWay":"暂无数据","stuFarmer":"否","stuEnteranceDate":"2010","stuPolitical":"zzzz","stuNative"
:"美国","stuSpecial":"睡觉","stuSchoolRoll":"正常","regiousSeat":"无","stuMobile":"10002020010","stuAddress"
:"海底世界美滋滋","stuRegious":"无","stuBirth":"1900","stuNumber":"87654321","stuAlone":"否","stuClass":"1401"
,"stuEmail":"boomboomzz","stuHealth":"健康","stuName":"海绵宝宝","stuMartyr":"否","stuResidence":"海洋","stuNamed"
:"海绵宝宝","stuNation":"美国"}]}
```

But when I click the button to try to add data to the table, it alert like this:`DataTables warning: table id=testTable4 - Requested unknown parameter 'stuNumber' for row 1, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4`
So now I feel very confused and I don't know where the problem is?
Anyone help, I really appreciate that.

Comment: have you visited the link in the error? did you read it ?

Comment: Hi, when you defined your dataTable, at the `aoColumns` option you added a `stuNumber` column definition. But when you call your `GetStuInfoServlet` servlet and provided the data to show in the table, you didn't add `stuNumber` to your data, so it cannot be parsed into your table.

Comment: @lgorovics Hi, yes, I didn't set the aoColumns option, now it perfect works, thank U.